# How to detect the touch point of iCarouselButtonDemo?

Tags: ios, icarousel

I am using `iCarouselButtonDemo` to create an arc button menu. I want to disable the scrolling when user touch the space other than the buttons. But now we can scroll the view by touching every point of the `UIView`. How can I detect the touch point of the view and disable the scrolling when user touch the outside of the 5 buttons

[image]

This is my view. This is scrolling when I touch even the bottom of the view. How can I stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the iCarousel implementation file, you will add the following code in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` method. So it looks like this. It firstly get the touch point in the iCarousel view, and find the inner most view responding to the touch through hitTest. If the view is not a button, you stop the pan gesture.

```
if ([gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
{
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self];
    UIView *touchedView = [self hitTest:point withEvent:nil];

    if (![touchedView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    //ignore vertical swipes
```